# Django create nested json using single model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django rest framewrok, my data is stored in database as shown in below. Here "name" column includes different organization name, and I am trying is to group data based on different organization name and create json response as shown below.

[image]

**Json:**

```
  [
  {
    "org1": [
      {
        "address": "france",
        "phone": "3"
      },
      {
        "address": "uk",
        "phone": "4"
      },
      {
        "address": "ind",
        "phone": "99"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "org2": [
      {
        "address": "Uk",
        "phone": "8997"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**model, serializer and viewset are shown below**

```
 class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerEvents
        fields = ('name','address','phone',)

class OrganizationSerializerViewSet(generics.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer


class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)
        db_table = 'org'
```

Please help me how can I achieve this using DRF?

Thank you

Comment: Actually this looks more like bad modeling to me. You should normalize the database: create a model `Organization`, and a model `Address` and make a `ForeignKey` form `Address` to `Organization`, then you can use [*nested relationships*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: there other REST api call uses same model and database modification now is difficult :(, is it not at all possible to achieve above json structure using existing model  :) please suggest

Comment: it is, but this way of modeling is simply not NF1 form, which means it is really bad. This results in large inefficient databases that take complex queries, and long time to answer those queries.

Comment: agree, normalization concept is not there, as data grows response time becomes slower, but I will leave with it. please provide some answer :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the table is not normalised as NF1?  ... yes it is.